# Using Different nav_menu_css_class for different nav_walkers

Tags: navigation, walker

On my theme I have to different nav_walkers, I'd like to be able to call two different nav_menu_css_class-es for each menu alas, they appear to apply globally. Here's what I have

```
function onpage_nav_menu_css_class($classes, $item) {
    $slug = sanitize_title($item->title);
    $classes = preg_replace('/(current(-menu-|[-_]page[-_])(item))/', 'active', $classes);
    $classes = preg_replace('/(current(-menu-|[-_]page[-_])(ancestor|parent))/', '', $classes);
    $classes = preg_replace('/^((menu|page)[-_\w+]+)+/', '', $classes);

    $classes[] = 'menu-' . $slug;

    $classes = array_unique($classes);

    return array_filter($classes, 'is_element_empty');
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'onpage_nav_menu_css_class', 1, 2);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', '__return_null');
```

Answer (score 0):

The [third parameter passed into `nav_menu_css_classes`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L99) should give you the information you need to sort out the different menus. Try:

```
function onpage_nav_menu_css_class($classes, $item, $args) {
  var_dump($args);
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'onpage_nav_menu_css_class', 1, 3);
```

Note: That will make a mess of your page. It is debugging/development only code.
I think that the `theme_location` should be sufficient for your purposes. Just check that value and conditionally apply your classes based on that.